# React Native computational heavy task

Tags: asynchronous, react-native, realm, background-process, redux-observable

Very simple and common use case, but I can't find satisfying answer.
I have react native app which needs to store some data locally. I am using redux and redux-observables and Realm as a storage.

What I need is: some action occur, let's say ADD_ITEM. I need to update UI with some payload (standard redux). Then I want to create/transform that payload to another piece of data and save that data into Realm (asynchronously). Whatever I try, it always lags UI (a lot).

I tried to wrap that realm call into promise and use switchMap, but it's still slow.

I haven't took a look at workers yet but they only accept strings, which is let's say much less usable for me.

I can offload completely that computation to native background thread but that will be very uncomfortable and a lot of writing.

Could async await help me? Of redux-saga? I feel like it's the same thing, not real async processing.

Or am I using completely wrong libraries for this?

```
const insertOrderItem = (action$) =>
    action$.ofType(Action.ADD_ORDER_ITEM)
        .switchMap(({ payload }) => Rx.Observable.fromPromise(
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                storage.insert(createObject(payload)
                resolve({
                    type: "OPERATION_ADDED"
                })
            })
        ))
```

In general, storing small piece of data to realm shouldn't be THAT much computational heavy but I feel like it's necessary to do this kind of jobs on background thread.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I had same problem with my app using React Native + Realm DB. I tried all ways without having to write native code and make the bridge from react-native to native, and finally I found a solution:

https://corbt.com/posts/2015/12/22/breaking-up-heavy-processing-in-react-native.html

1. Install `npm install next-frame --save`.
2. Add next-frame to your code `import nextFrame from 'next-frame';`
3. Add this line within a for that took long, or a for which insert in DB `await nextFrame();`

A complete example would look like this:

```
import nextFrame from 'next-frame';

let response = await fetch("https://emberall.com/user/1/recordings");
let responseJSON = await response.json();

for (let recording of responseJSON.recordings) {
  await nextFrame(); // The javascript will yield here and not resume execution until the next frame. 
  mergeRecordingToLocalDatabase(recording);
}
```

Basically what this does is that in every iteration or db-insert it waits for JS to render and process next UI frame, so your app will not get stuck or freeze.

P.D.: I know months have passed since question but I think a lot o people could benefit from this.

Answer (score 2):

It's laggy because JS run in one thread. So if you wrap your code in Promise, it's still in one thread.

I think best solution for your is transfer data over React Native bridge to native and do this transform in native code. [For guide how to communicate with native code look here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/communication-ios.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Realm, but I can't seem to find the `storage.insert` API you're using. I only see [`realm.write()`](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#writes) transactions. I was trying to see if they had a truly non-blocking, asynchronous API but it appears Realm does not offer one for their JavaScript bindings.

They do appear to offer non-blocking APIs in their Java bindings with [`executeTransactionAsync()`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#asynchronous-transactions) but that is not likely an option for you.

Seems like your options would be: do it in native on another thread, or some how reduce the write overhead (smaller object, write at a time where it's not noticeable, etc)

Comment: storage.insert is just wrapper for realm.write. yeah, java will not help, but thanks.